# What's the use of Stateless Widget if one can directly return a widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

This might be an odd question but I'm wondering what's the actual use of stateless widget if one can simply return a widget? Stateful widgets on the other hand are useful for handling states because of setState method. Are stateless widget only useful because of access to BuildContext variable?

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "Direct",
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TITLE"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child:  Text("TITLE"),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

The above code works and shows the basic AppBar and Body without using a stateless widget.

Comment: `Text` actually is a `StatelessWidget`

Comment: You don't need a state if you have only one way of turning model data from the outside into a view within the widget tree.